# Eclipse PDE: Do I need to include SWT package for PDE applications?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have:

```
* a bundle
* a target file for that bundle
* a feature
* a update site
```

When I build the update site, the update site includes the feature which in turn includes the bundle.

The problem I am having is that the Target file defines no operating system and uses the default of my host (Windows) I would like it to also include Linux aswell so that the org.eclipse.swt package is also valid for Linux if that is necessary. Eclipse plugin works well under Windows.

Am I expected to do something different for plugins which work under Linux?

The SWT.COLOR_WHITE id is not the correct one on Linux and I am getting an IllegalArgument exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4576)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4510)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control._setBackground(Control.java:4546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBackground(Control.java:4537)
```

Given by

```
        sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
        Composite composite = new OverallComposite(sc, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED, this);
        Color white = Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);

        this line -> composite.setBackground(white);
```

If I create a colour like this:

```
Device device = Display.getCurrent();
java.awt.Color c = java.awt.Color.decode(this.data.colour);
Color color = new Color(device, c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());
```

I do not get an exception.

In the definition XML file I notice plugins such as the following:

```
    <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.**win32.x86_64**"/>
```

Note: I am not using Tycho or maven, I am using eclipses internal build system.

Comment: There is no platform independent SWT, you need a separate build for each platform. Other parts of Eclipse are also platform dependent.

Comment: However the API defined by SWT is always the same and SWT.COLOR_WHITE always has the same value so I don't follow how you are getting an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: How would I build for the two platforms? Do I need to open it in Linux and build it?

Comment: You have to add the Delta Pack to your target platform which is unfortunately no longer provided directly as a download for current versions as in the past: https://wiki.eclipse.org/A_Brief_Overview_of_Building_at_Eclipse#What_if_you_really_want_the_traditional_Delta_Pack_zip_file.3F

Comment: Is there a way to use the SWT on the eclipse platform rather than have my own SWT bundled?

Comment: Are you building a complete RCP or just a feature to include in an existing Eclipse? If it is just a feature it shouldn't include the SWT plugins as the correct platform versions will already be in the existing Eclipse. If the feature has no platform dependencies itself you only need one build of that.

Comment: I don't think your IllegalArgumentException is anything to do with wrong versions of SWT - that just would not run at all. Checking the Linux source the IllegalArgumentException is because the Color parameter has been disposed. We need to see a [mcve] to determine why.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks greg for your comments, both are helpful, I am building a feature ill check for the dispose.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks a lot greg-449 for your help, it did appear to be a problem with disposing the colours. Do you have an Amazon Wishlist I could thank you with something?

Comment: No need, just having helped is enough